# How to generate 2 uncorrelated list in python?

Tags: python, numpy, correlation

I want to have 2 vector with length like 30+, which are uncorrelated to each other(corr = 0), I can generate by hand, but is there any function providing that feature for me in python?

corr（l1，l2）=0

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. You can generate 30 value points of sin(x) function and 30 value points for, say, y=x^2. They will be independent and thus uncorrelated.

Comment: @khachik Sine and cosine may be an even better example.

Comment: Or maybe look at the multivariate_normal, only problem is the tolerance

Comment: @khachik, as I put here, corr=0, give a list of 00001000, your example is correlated technically.